# cmd java relative path

Tags: java, command-line, batch-file

I need to run a java class in cmd line. How would I run a java class without changing directories, but instead specify a relative path? I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
java -cp ./lib/*; ./bin/javaclass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set classpath till the bin folder.

```
java -cp ./lib/*;./bin com.foo.MyJavaClass
```

Comment: I'm guessing its the same for absolute paths also?